# Is $\exists x,\ a_1, ... a_{n}$ $\in \mathbf{N}\ {\gt 0}$ such that $x^{n} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i}^n$ true for any positive integer $n$?

Tags: diophantine-equations

> Is $\exists x,\ a_1, ... a_{n}$ such that $x^{n} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i}^n$ true for any positive integer $n$?

Fermat's last theorem got me thinking if it's possible to split a hypercube of dimension $n$ with the length of each side being an integer into $n$ smaller hypercubes whose sides are also integer-valued, at least in principle. This is because of the way Fermat explained his theorem (that it's impossible to split a cube or any other higher power into two other cubes).

So, can you split a hypercube of dimension $n$ with integer sides into $n$ other smaller hypercubes also having integer sides? I'm not a mathematician, I'm just curious.

Comment: By "integer", you meant "positive integer" I guess? Otherwise, $x=1$ and $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)=(1,0,\dots,0)$ would be a (trivial) solution.

Comment: Yes, I'll make that more explicit.

Comment: $27^5+84^5+110^5+133^5=144^5$ ([Lander and Parkin](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1966-72-06/S0002-9904-1966-11654-3/S0002-9904-1966-11654-3.pdf)). There is a conjecture (no counterexamples known) that you need at least $n-1$ n-th powers to make an n-th power.

Comment: Some sums using exactly $n$ n-th powers:
$3^3 + 4^3 + 5^3 = 6^3$, $30^4 + 120^4 + 272^4 + 315^4 = 353^4$, $7^5 + 43^5 + 57^5 + 80^5 + 100^5 = 107^5$. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lander,_Parkin,_and_Selfridge_conjecture)

Comment: The [Jacobi-Madden equation][1] has an infinite number of non-zero solutions.

$a^4 + b^4 + c^4 + d^4 = (a+b+c+d)^4$

[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Madden_equation